# Increase value of digit within HTML string (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing

I have a bunch of images in a folder which are all named as numbers. The first one is displayed on document load.

```
<img src="image/01.jpg" />
```

I want to use jQuery to flick through the images. In other words, I want to convert the HTML to a string and then increase the value of what is currently "01".

So far I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var $n = $("img").html(htmlString(17));
    $n.val(Number($n.val())+1);
  }); 
});
```

The bit that I'm sure I'm completely wrong on is the selecting of the digit (i.e delcaring `var $n`. I've tried to convert the HTML to a string there and count along the characters but I'm not even sure if that's the right route to be taking; I can't find anything similar anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: you could use data- attributes to store in current and maximum number.  Use jQuery to pull the current value, increment if less than max, then set the src for the image.

Comment: What is `htmlString(17)` doing?

Comment: @Andreas I was trying to select the digit from the string of HTML. I think I was wrongly doing it the way that you select HTML content though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`img` element doesn't have html content, apart from that you are using `html` as setter not getter. You can replace the `src` attribute's value using `replace` method:

```
$('img').prop('src', function(_, src) {
    return src.replace(/\d+/, function(n) {
        var num = +n + 1;
        return num.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + num.toString() : num;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bb84Q/

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems to do it. To further my understanding of this answer, could you please explain which part of the code selects the digit to be changed? There's quite a bit in there I haven't seen before.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer You are welcome, I have used regular expression, `/\d+/` selects the integer value.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Just did some reading up on regex, very useful. One more question- What is the significance of the underscore in "function(_, src)"?

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer `_` is the `index`, `prop` iterates through all the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = "image/01.jpg";
var number = source.split(".")[0].split("/")[1];
number = (number *1) + 1
var newsource = "image/" + number + ".jpg";
```

this is how you'd actually get source

```
var source = $("img").attr('src');
```

just realized that this will make "image/2.jpg"  , you could use a `data-number` attribute, you could re-name the images that are 1 - 9 , but this gives you an idea

Answer (score 0):

You can just

1)catch the src value in a js variable

2) using substr function get rid of the "image/" part.

3) Then using split() on "." take the first array slot's value.

4)Convert that to integer using intVal() and

5) then increment the value